# concatenate multi-line log entries

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a large log file with various entries as below (`\n` indicates a newline):

```
111111,GO,2018-08-09 14:10:32.805,1,xxxxxxxxx,yyyy,I                          \n
  ,NAME-01/0.3-445.44,,                                                       \n
                                                                              \n
222222,STOP,.......................
```

Each log entry starts with a 5-to-9 digit number. Sometimes, a log entry is split over multiple lines. When this happens, the log entry satisfies the following conditions:

- the first log-entry line starts with the 5-to-9 digit number
- all consecutive lines start with a sequence of blanks followed by a `,` <comma>
- the last of the log-entry might only contain blanks
- each line of the log-entry has the same length and is padded with blanks.

The above example shows that the first log entry is such a case. The second not.

however as indicated in the above example,

I would like to concatenate the multi-line entries into a single line and delete all spurious spaces.

the result of the above should become:

```
111111,GO,2018-08-09 14:10:32.805,1,xxxxxxxxx,yyyy,I,NAME-01/0.3-445.44,,
222222,STOP,.......................
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Not clear, please use code tags properly, though I tried to edit your post but it didn't show samples properly, please do so along with explanation of your question.

Comment: Am I also right to understand that the character sequence `\n` is referencing a newline or are these characters actually written in your file?

Comment: Sorry to ask you all these questions. We really are here to help you out and help you improve your skil set. But at the moment the conditions are still unclear to us, so it is hard for us to come up with a fitting answer to your question.

Comment: @kvantour: \n is referencing a newline and all the line have the same length

Comment: @Frank74 I have updated your question to make it more clear. Please update or revert if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the conditions you wrote, a tool which might help you out is Awk:

```
awk '!/^[[:blank:]]+(,|$)/{print p; p=""}
     { gsub(/(^[[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]*$)/,"",$0); p = p $0 }
     END {print p}' logfile
```

This outputs:

```
111111,GO,2018-08-09 14:10:32.805,1,xxxxxxxxx,yyyy,I,NAME-01/0.3-445.44,,
222222,STOP,.......................
```

It works in the following way:

1. **`!/^[[:blank:]]+(,|$)/{print p; p=""}`:** Every time a line is found which does not start with blanks followed by a comma or just blanks, it will print a variable `p` which holds the log entry and clear out that variable.
2. **`{ gsub(/(^[[:blank:]]*|[[:blank:]]*$)/,"",$0); p = p $0 }`:** It will always concatenate the current log-file line to the variable `p` but first, it will have removed all blanks at the beginning and end of that line.
3. **`END {print p}`:** when the end of the file is reached, it still needs to print a single log-entry which was constructed.

Comment: Your welcome. As a final thing, please remove any spurious comments which are not needed anymore (essentially all of them as all information is now in the question) just to keep it in line with SO's idea of comments. And most importantly, Welcome to Stack Overflow ;-)

Comment: Thank you again. I delete comment useless.